# Unity - Sprite Packer is disabled

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I open "Sprite Packer" window I see info "Legacy sprite packer is disabled. Enable it in Edit>Project Settings>Editor". So I open this settings, but there "Sprite Packer > Mode" is set to "Always Enabled". But in Sprite Packer window I still have previous info and I can't use it.

So why I can't use it, and how to turn it on?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of your program? I had the same problem. Try this: 1) Move the assets outside the resource folder.
2) Disable and re-enable the sprite packer from the Project Settings > Editor
3) Close the project and reopen it
4) Reapply the PackingTag by changing it & hit "Apply" again

Comment: I'm using Unity 2017.3 free version. I did what you wrote but still is disabled.

Comment: Have you found the solution to this issue? as i'm facing the same issue in Unity 2017.3.0f3

Answer (score 1):

Goto `Edit > Project Settings > Editor`

Just figured out that somehow `Always Enabled` in `Sprite Packer > Mode` is not working, but you can use `Always Enabled (Legacy Sprite Packer)`.

This is a workaround for Unity 2017.3.0f3

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because Unity detects that you have no Sprite Atlas assets.

Create a new **Sprite Atlas** object in your Assets. Open the Sprite Atlas and look under **Objects for Packing**. Add your Sprites/Images (or folder) here then click Pack Preview.

[image]

Now you don't need to use the legacy Sprite Packer tool (in the Window menu).

Comment: Is it still important with Sprite Atlas that the "Packing Tag" on each of the sprites is specified?